# Want to see a wordpress site which runs in localhost at server computer from client computer

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

**I** build a webisite with wordpress and i want to show my website to other client computers
I run xampp server at server computer
How can i do for that?
plz answer quickly..**

Comment: If it's just for a presentation you can use webex/gotomeeting/livemeeting/etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the web server is accessible from the client's computer, you'll need to give connect from the client using the machine's IP address or hostname.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a dynamic hostname, [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com) offers them.

Answer (score 0):

Or put xampp it in sync folder of Dropbox. I'm using it like that. Synced from home, then when i open it from work, i got it there too.